# Активный пункт меню?

Tags: css3, html, javascript

Вот [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/nb3gu/11/) весь код.

Мне очень нужно сделать так, что бы при нажатии на вложенный пункт меню, основной становился активным. Например, при нажатии на подпункт существительные пункт словарь становился активным.

Не могу понять, как это делается. Подскажите кто знает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#navi>ul>li').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#navi li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).children('a').toggleClass('active');
        });
    });​
```

Comment: только вот у меня внутри этого клика после добавления класса идет загрузка файла 
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(url);
что теперь с ней делать?

Comment: она теперь в подпунктах не работает

Comment: я там код обновил

Comment: честно говоря решение лишено изящности, но в вашем случае сработает:

      $('#navi>ul>li').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var url = $(e.originalEvent.originalTarget).parent().attr('href');
         $('#content').load(url);
            $('#navi li a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).children('a').toggleClass('active');
   
        });

Comment: Спасибо! Главное, что работает!!!